# UITextField in TableView Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

iam trying to add UITextField dynamically into TableView this is my code

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
textField.tag=temp+indexPath.row+1;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

the problem is each time display a cell it creates a newTextField in the same position so they overLap and i cant edit in the other TextField and they have the same Tag..
i want to creat a TextField only one time for Each Cell even if it will be displayed again

Comment: check if (cell==nil) then create cell with textfiled otherwise that will reuse the cells to avoid textfiled creation more than once.

Comment: @sugan.s If a cell is registered for reuse, it will not be nil.

Comment: yah at first time when tableview is loaded that time cell will be nil.@Anupdas

Comment: @sugan.s Can you support your statement. Read documentation of – [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:). This method always returns a valid cell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom UITableViewCell class

### TableViewCellWithTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewCellWithTextField : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,strong) UITextField *textField;
@end
```

### TableViewCellWithTextField.m

```
@implementation TableViewCellWithTextField

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
        [self addSubview:_textField];
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

### And then You can use your textfield like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * cellIdentifier= @"Cell"
    TableViewCellWithTextField *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[TableViewCellWithTextField alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textField.tag = temp + indexPath.row + 1;
}
```

Comment: i think this will make do difference because cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called every time u will display cell so the same cell will be called more than once and we will have the same problem

Comment: This **will** make the difference. New TableViewCellWithTextFields will only be instantiated when there aren't any that can be dequeued, and the UITextField is only added to the Cell when it is first instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using causes memory leaks, as you know. So you can create a custom cell which has textview as property and access to textview in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Every cell has only one textview, which is accessible by property, like you access the label of the cell.

Another way is you access the textview using tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method instead of creating every time.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably give all the text fields (no matter what table view cell they are in) the same tag TEXT_FIELD_TAG where

```
#define TEXT_FIELD_TAG 1000
```

Every time tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, you should check whether  a subview with TEXT_FIELD_TAG already exists, like this:

```
UITextField *textField = [cell.contentView viewWithTag: TEXT_FIELD_TAG];
if(!textField){
    textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    textField.tag=temp+indexPath.row+1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
}
```

If textField = nil then you need to create a new UITextField and add it to the content view.

Comment: thats really working man,,thanks a lot for inspiration but it needs some enhancement to give each TextField unique Tag so that i can get the value in them later....

Answer (score 0):

i finally discovered it with your help DEFINITELY

```
if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:temp+indexPath.row+1 ]) {
     UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];

    textField.tag=temp+indexPath.row+1;

    textField.delegate=self;

    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
   // textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

so that here i will guarantee that i will Create the UITextField only once per Cell...

```
}
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers then please accept it.

Comment: @Ulugbek's solution of subclassing UITableViewCell is far more elegant and reusable ...